# JWT integration with django

Tags: python, django, jwt, json-web-token

I am new to Django (not DRF) and I have a hard time configuring my authentication requirements. I have an external authentication service that gets a username and password and returns a JWT. After I have the JWT how should I save the token and provide it with every request from the browser. And after that where can I validate it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For every call that your service get there should be header to that call

```
{'Authorization':'Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b'}
```

And you can use that in views.py as :

```
            if request.user.is_authenticated():
```

It has to be included in the settings file of that django project.

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    # 'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER':
    # 'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_encode_handler',

    # 'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER':
    # 'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_decode_handler',

    # 'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    # 'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler',

    # 'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USER_ID_HANDLER':
    # 'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_get_user_id_from_payload_handler',

    # 'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    # 'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler',

    # 'JWT_SECRET_KEY': settings.SECRET_KEY,
    # 'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    # 'JWT_VERIFY': True,
    # 'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': False,
    # 'JWT_LEEWAY': 0,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=1),
    # 'JWT_AUDIENCE': None,
    # 'JWT_ISSUER': None,

    # 'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': False,
    # 'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=7),

    # 'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',
}
```

Read more about it [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication).